# When I click on link under menu which is inside the iframe, it opens the new browser window

Tags: selenium, iframe, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In below code of selenium script to access iframe elements.
I open a menu in first webElement and and then in second webElement I click on link watches under menu. 
It redirects the page properly but it opens same page in new browser window also.
i.e. 2 browser are opened.  How to prevent new browser to be opened.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("watches_iframe")));
Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pm-        
nav']//div[@class='pm-menu-button']"));
menu.click();


// when I click on below link it redirects the page properly but opens same 
// page in new window also

WebElement store = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pm-menu-
master']//li[@class='item-store']//a//span[1]"));
store.click();
```

Comment: Check this manually and confirm whether 2 browsers are opening up.

Comment: No.. in manually steps it opens in same window.
Does it load/refresh iframe every time we select any link on iframe?

Comment: @MSD Which browser & version are you using?

Comment: @MSD to add to the previous comment - which Driver/version are you using? Also, why are you clicking a span in a <a> control? Should you just click the <a> control?